# Python effecient conversion of audio stream PCM string to array, for repeated use

Tags: python, arrays, string, memory, audio

Hi I want to convert an audio stream recorded via the microphone to an array of ints (or floats or whatever) for later analysis (fft etc). However my current method strikes me as a little inefficient, and I think I am seeing sporadic memory allocation delays.

I am using alsaaudio as ossaudiodev no longer works on most Linux distributions, but it shouldn't really matter. The audio stream I get out of the device is a string of 2048 chars which corresponds to the 1024 16bit audio frames. I thought that "array" was the best way to convert the string to an array of ints, however at the end of each loop I have to clear the array for the next round of data which I do with `del` and if look at the time it takes for the loop internals to run (not including the read) I see that every 4th or 5th (it's sporadic) loop will take much longer, so my question is in terms of memory allocation is my current strategy efficient?

The audio device was set up like this:

```
import array
import alsaaudio as alsa
audio_data = array.array("h")
ain = alsa.PCM(alsa.PCM_CAPTURE,alsa.PCM_NORMAL,card='default')
ain.setchannels(1)
ain.setrate(rate)
ain.setformat(alsa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
ain.setperiodsize(1024)
```

then inside a loop I do this

```
Nsamples,astream = ain.read()
audio_data.fromstring(astream)
## some analysis is done (FFT, plot whatever)
# i.e. 
Freq = np.abs(sy.fft(audio_data))
# clear the audio data array for next segment
del audio_data[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try numpy.fromstring ?